# Running microservice go (not found)

Tags: docker, go, microservices

The error I'm getting for my Go Module project

> /bin/sh: microservice: not found

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.7.4-alpine
MAINTAINER John Doe

ENV SOURCES /go/src/github.com/john/app/

COPY . ${SOURCES}

RUN cd ${SOURCES} && cgo_enabled=0 go install

ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT microservice
```

**microservice.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(port(), nil)
}

func port() string {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    fmt.Println(port)
    if len(port) == 0 {
        port = "8080"
    }
    return ":" + port
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World.")
}
```

It's a Go module project. I've created an image using following command.

```
docker build -t app:1.0.3 .
```

and running it via

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 app:1.0.3
```

Comment: Try passing the ENTRYPOINT file using it's full path. Also make sure it is being copied properly.

Comment: you mean update docker file like this `ENTRYPOINT ${SOURCES}microservice`

Comment: try `echo $PATH, $GOBIN` in the docker file, you may find something

Comment: @zzn I'm new to docker, i added echo and it gave me this error. `Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 13: unknown instruction: ECHO
`

Comment: why negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created executable file is at /go/bin/app
and current working directory is /go.

So, change the last line of your Dockerfile to this

```
ENTRYPOINT ./bin/app
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. I've another issue, if all my sources are in the root directory, it works but if i move one of the file to a subdirectory let's say `api/books.go` I get an error executing `docker build` command

Comment: I think, the problem is not docker specific, but golang build system specific. Please look for solutions to how to compile golang sources.

Comment: ok, also is this `./bin/app`, the word app is a fixed or is it because of my github url from `ENV SOURCES /go/src/github.com/john/app/`

Comment: Updating the Dockerfile to use a multi-stage build, and copying the go-service executable to a 'scratch' image is a worthwhile investment. Your image size drops essentially the size of the exe - losing all the now unneeded build image bloat.